# Find force $F$ for equilibrium?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, equilibrium, statics

[image]

The masses of all the objects are mentioned inside them.

Masses of both inclined planes are same and angle of inclination is same too.The inclines are smooth and the bar is Rigid.

We have to find the value of the force $F$ as applied in the figure for the system to be in equilibrium.

While attempting this question I thought that 'F' could take any value as it is applied from opposite directions and the force will be cancelled. But I am sure that this would not be the correct solution. Please give the solution with the suitable explanation and why would the forces not cancel out as they are being applied on the same system?

Here is my approach:

[image]

Please tell me where am I going wrong or am I correct?

Comment: Please read the [homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) for these types of questions.  We require you to show some effort and ask conceptual questions.  As it stands now, this reads as "solve this problem and show your work for me", which is not something we generally do here.  That wont help you understand.

Comment: Are the surfaces of the triangles rough or smooth?

Comment: Hint: $M$ wants to fall. The only thing keeping it from falling is the normal force from the two inclined surfaces. The only thing supplying the normal for for each inclined surface is the applied force and the normal force from the ground. Draw a FBD for each object and the answer should flow from there

Comment: You are right that the two equal but opposite forces cancel out - but only seen from outside this "system". The inside of this "system" can move around. In other words, the external forces cancel out if this system was *rigid*, but it isn't.

Comment: @JMac I would keep that in mind for future but just to let you know I tried this question and I was not sure of the answer and which part of this question is missing 'concepts'. It is NOT MY HOMEWORK.  If you could read the whole description where I mentioned my problem in this question

Comment: @Steeven all surfaces are frictionless

Comment: @NippunSharma The line "Please give the solution with the suitable explanation and why would the forces not cancel out as they are being applied on the same system?" is asking for something we don't do.  You want a full outlined answer to a "homework type" question; which is against site policy.  You haven't really outlined what happens when you try to apply any force.  If you did the analysis you might see what is really happening here.

Comment: @Jim Wouldn't the weight of 'M' would also contribute to the normal force?

Comment: @NippunSharma The weight of $M$ is cancelled by the two normal forces but it doesn't supply them. The triangles would just slide away without providing normal forces without the applied forces and normal forces from the ground. There's a difference between contributing forces and generating forces

Comment: @NippunSharma we agree that this is not homework question.But make it sure that you have read PSE's homework policy.You need to show at least some working in the form of Free Body Diagrams ,Concepts used and you must be precise and to the point with the concept you want to ask.

Comment: Please look  at my approach and tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: We are not really a "check my work" website.

Comment: @JMac What do you want me to do or ask? I have given my approach towards the question.

Comment: If you are not able to explain the concept behind the question then there is no need for you to criticize others.

Comment: We generally focus on conceptual physics questions.  "How to solve this" and "check my work" questions don't really fit well with the intent of the site.

Comment: and where is this question lacking concept?

Comment: @NippunSharma You're asking about a specific solution to a specific problem (especially in the "check my work" case).  The "concept" here has to do with the basic scenario.  A question like "Why couldn't F be any value of force in this situation?" and then explaining your reasoning on cancelling forces; would be more along the lines of questions that fit here.    That also seems to be the concept Steeven addressed.  It's not really this sites purpose to confirm that you are applying the math properly based on the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets consider the left side wedge to be wedge 1 and the right one to be wedge 2. Considering the block, the wedge 1 exerts a force N1(normal reaction) on the block, the wedge 2 a force N2 and the Earth exerts a force Mg. The wedge 1 experiences normal reaction N1 and a force mg exerted by the Earth. The wedge 2 the force N2 and the force mg.

For the block, 
[image]

So, we hence N1=N2=N ( we consider N instead of N1 and N2 as the normal force for the sake of simplicity ).

Now, for wedge 1,[image]

Since the same one counts for wedge 2 too, I ain't uploading the image for wedge 2.

Finally your solution counts as [image]

So your solution is obviously correct to the point.

Next coming to your doubt.The cancelling out of forces etc depends on the way you consider the problem.
If you consider the system of the block and wedges as a whole. You see that even though there is "Internal Movement" inside the system you considered due to "Internal forces" like normal reaction, the system as a whole isn't moving. Hence the total external force acting on the system as a whole would be zero.
Hence the External forces F should cancel each other. But if you consider block or wedge by wedge,like we would take for solving problems and equations( like we took here), the forces acting on a particular wedge, lets take it to be wedge 1, has to sum up to be zero since the wedge is in equilibrium. Hence, like we considered it the above problem, the force F is cancelled out by the sine component of the normal force N and vertically, the sum of the cosine component of N and the weight mg is cancelled out by the normal force N'. So, When you come into the system, you can build your distinct relations on how the the external forces cancel out each other.
Saying it more simply, suppose this system is just a part of another huge problem and the movements taking place inside the system is of no concern for the the outside the system, then you just consider the external forces F to cancel each other. But if the inside of the system (i.e., the wedges and the block ) is a concern for your problem, then you take it block and wedge by wedge and solve like we did above. 
Please take it to your attention that as F vary the wedges and block may or may not move.And if this "may or may not"movement is of no concern for your question, you just consider the system as a whole. But if this is a matter of concern for your question, then you has to consider the inside too ( block and wedge by wedge ).

Answer (score 1):

That forces "*will be cancelled*" if they are equal and opposite is essentially only correct, if they push **directly on one another**. But in general they don't. In general there is always something in between.

Sometimes this "something" is *rigid*. Then it makes no difference because the forces are transmitted directly and un-altered through it, so that the forces again cancel out. Of this reason you very often see in e.g. textbook exercises that such in-between objects are assumed rigid - it simply makes the tasks simpler to solve (and it is very often a good assumption when objects are hard and strong and un-flexible).

But in your case the in-between "something" is *not rigid*. It is not one rigid object but consists of several objects that can move around. Then the external forces can do changes and put accelerations on these objects until they again are still.

*All in all the short answer is*: Equal and opposite forces in general never just cancel out. We often assume something to be rigid so that they do, but whenever something internally is moving around, we must be careful and can't just assume this.

> Please give the solution with the suitable explanation

Let me give a hint:

Draw the force diagram for each object. Dont' forget the normal forces at each contact surface. Then set up Newton's 1st law for each object. You should have enough known and unknown variables here to solve it.

**Update**

On your added solution on the very first picture you start with assumption something called $M/R$. I do not see what this $R$ is or why this is necessary. Also, there are several arrows on the contact surfaces, but only one is necessary as one normal force (on each surface).

When you draw the force diagrams:

- The left triangle will have force $F$ rightwards and a normal force $n$ **perpendicularly** into the tilted surface. A normal force is always perpendicular.
- The right triangle will have force $F$ leftwards and a normal force $n$ **perpendicularly** into the tilted surface.

Because there is symmetry, you can assume both normal forces equal (the burden on each triangle is the same; no uneven mass or uneven forces.) Otherwise you would have had to call them $n_1$ and $n_2$.

- The bar will have it's weight $w=Mg$ downwards, a normal force $n$ **perpendicular** to the left titled surface inwards and also a normal force $n$ **perpendicular** to the right titled surface inwards.

We could also include the triangle weights downwards as well as a normal force from the ground upwards on each triangle. Do that if you are in doubt (but I'm pretty sure they will cancel out and not have any influence. As far as I can tell without solving this all the way, there is no need for the vertical direction on the triangles.).

Now you can set up Newton's 1st law; one equation for the horizontal direction for each object and maybe also one vertically for the bar. That should do it, it looks like.

Comment: I edited my question please tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: @NippunSharma See my edit. I hope this helps. Your solution looks way too complicated. Just consider the normal force as *one* force on each of the two surfaces and forget about trying to split up the mass and have a fraction of the mass "applied" on each triangle. That is not the way to do Newton's laws unless when the bar has in-even mass (unless you are using a method I've never seen before).